# How to calculate amount to be paid from input box values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a problem in automatically calculating the amount to be paid in a html table.

The html code looks like this:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" id="getAvailability" readonly class="form-control input-sm" />
    <strong>Qty</strong><br />
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="Qty" id="getQty" class="form-control input-sm NumbersOnly" />
</td>
<td>
    <strong>Rate</strong><br />
    <input type="text" name="Rate" id="getRate" readonly class="form-control input-sm " />
</td>
<td>
    <strong>Amount</strong><br />
    <input type="text" name="Amount" id="getAmount" readonly class="form-control input-sm " />
</td>
```

Bellow this table i have another table with SQL entries, from where i select a row. On clicking a row from this table the following function is called:

```
$(function () {
        $('#getStockID').val($.trim(cells[0].innerHTML));
        $('#getItem').val($.trim(cells[1].innerHTML));
        $('#getAvailability').val($.trim(cells[3].innerHTML));                       
        $('#getRate').val($.trim(cells[4].innerHTML));
    });
```

When i enter the quantity in first table i would like to have to amount to be paid calculated:

```
$('#getQty').keyup(function () {
    var available = Number($('#getAvailability').val());
    var quantity = Number($('#getQty').val());
    var rate = Number($('#getRate').val());
    if (quantity > available) {
        $('#getQty').val(available);
        quantity = available;
    }
    var amount = (quantity * rate);               
    $("#getAmount").val(amount.toFixed(2));
});
```

Using this code, i get NaN in the cell.
Please advice, i spent way too many hours on this issue, and i'm out of ideas.
Thank you very much!

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: if($('#getAvailability').val().trim() !=''){ 
 var available  = $('#getAvailability').val().trim();  }else{ alert("empty"); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone text box has empty value this problem will occur.So that you have to use **isNaN** in javascript.

```
$('#getQty').keyup(function () {
    var available = chkIsNaN(Number($('#getAvailability').val()));
    var quantity = chkIsNaN(Number($('#getQty').val()));
    var rate = chkIsNaN(Number($('#getRate').val()));
    if (quantity > available) {
        $('#getQty').val(available);
        quantity = available;
    }
    var amount = (quantity * rate);               
    $("#getAmount").val(amount.toFixed(2));
});

function chkIsNaN(val){
if(isNaN(val)){
return '';
}
else{
return val;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, now it displays "0.00", not NaN, but i does not calculate the value. I think it's a problem with the "rate" value because if i set amount =(quantity*2) the value displayed it's correct.

Comment: if you are passing space to Number function that will give you NaN.i think you no need to use Number function when you are validating text box as number

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that in "rate" cell the values are format like 30,00 but in the "amount" cell the value format is 10.00. It could be some regional settings, that the number format is not recognized?

Comment: 30,00 is not number that is string ..try to avoid

Comment: this is what i get from SQL database, the column is set to decimal(10,2).

Comment: Then use this: intval(str_replace(',', '', $rate))

Comment: In the meantime i changed my regional settings to use "." as separator for decimals and now it works. Thank you very much for your answers. Issue solved!